# Send data to TCP Server on local network with PhoneGap / jQuery mobile

Tags: jquery, cordova, tcp

I want to send this string "ABC" to a TCP Server on local network, and the address and port are available. And I want to do this with phonegap or jquery  mobile.

Any help?

Or, I have to make a proxy with PHP, and this PHP will handle the data send activity?

-Ana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery/PhoneGap itself does not support TCP protocol. Using a HTTP proxy for jQuery, or a native plugin for PhoneGap.

Answer (score -1):

try something like this?

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();

req.open("get", url, true);
req.send(null);
req.onerror = function () {
    alert("Error");
    console.log("ERROR");
};
req.onResult = new function() {
    alert("Success");
    console.log("SUCCESS");
};
```